# State not being passed in React Router v5

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When doing a `Redirect` in React Router v5, the pathname will work properly, but the additional `state` property is always undefined in the target component.

I'm using the default React Router SSR setup as seen here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/server-rendering/putting-it-all-together

I'm not sure if this is a SSR error, I need to add something to the SSR, or there's something I should be adding to the `to` object of the Redirect.

#### ClientSource.js

```
<Redirect from={from} to={{ pathname: path, state: { data } }} />;
```

#### ClientTarget.js

```
const TargetComponentContainer = ({ location }) => ( console.log(location) );
...
export default withRouter(CampaignPageContainer);
```

#### Route.js

```
<Route path="/:slug/:container" exact render={props => <TargetComponentContainer {...props} />} />
```

There are no errors really, when I access the state on the redirect target using `this.props.location.state`, it is `undefined`.

I appreciate any help out there.

Comment: Do you intend to have `path="/:slug...`?

FWIW, I was able to use your example to solve my problem. I was able to get the `location` in the child component using: 

`return (
            <div>{location.state.pmid}</div>
     )
`
and was using <Link> vs. <Redirect>

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are rigtht. The state can not pass.

## solution

You can add params in the search.There is a package is useful to you. The package name is `query-string`.

```
yarn add query-string
or
npm i query-string
```

## how to use?

```
import queryString from 'query-string';
const params = queryString.parse(window.location.search);
```

The params will display as an object.

```
eg: /detail?id=123456&name=fred
```

After parsing.You can get it like this.

```
{
  id: '123456',
  name: 'fred'
}
```

See more api about [query-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string)

Answer (score 0):

Lets pass some data with redirect:

```
<Redirect
    to={{
       pathname: "/signin",
       state: { from: props.location, alert: true },
     }}
 />
```

Then we can access it like that:

```
let location = useLocation()
function DashboardRedirectAlert() {
    if (location.state?.alert) {
      return <div className="alert alert-warning">Please Signin first</div>;
    } else {
      return <></>;
    }
  }
```